# Assets of Nuget PackageReference

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package, csproj

I have this packages in a project:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" Version="2.8.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" Version="2.8.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="2.8.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="2.8.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic" Version="2.8.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces" Version="2.8.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common" Version="2.8.2" />
```

I moved this .csproj file to 2017 format, and then, when I build the solution, there is an error:

> error CS0104: 'Project' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Project' and 'Some.Namespace.Project'

Of course, this error is because one of the packages described above moved to parent common project and conflicts with class with the same name.

My question is which assets (`IncludeAssets`, `ExcludeAssets`, `PrivateAssets`) should I set, with what value, and in which package?

For now, the .csproj file looks like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" Version="2.8.2">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="1.1.0">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" Version="2.8.2">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="2.8.2">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces" Version="2.8.2">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic" Version="2.8.2">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces" Version="2.8.2">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Common" Version="2.8.2">
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference>
```

But I think that this is not the best and precise option.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do here is to create a brand new blank project. Make a reference to the 2.8.2 version then compare what is in the csproj file against your real solution. Remove any references in your real solution that are not In your dummy file. It may well be that namespaces have changed, but at least once you get the references right, namespaces shouldn't be so difficult.

Comment: But my question is, if I **know** which reference I need- what the assets should I define?

Comment: Looking at the packageIncludes, it looks to me as though in the later version, the second line where version = 1.1.0 either no longer exists or it's namespace has changed into one of the existing ones. Exclude usually happens when you exclude but don't remove from the solution so chances are you can ignore those ones anyway. If you follow my answer things should become clearer. The 3 assetTypes that you talk about will be created by the parent package reference. You shouldn't need to touch these. for further clarification https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj